Can't find the issexpress.exe process to debug
I'm on visual studio 2019, trying to debug x++ code for D365 finance and operation, but when i want to attach the 'iisexpress.exe' process to start debugging, I can't find it, even after checking the "Show processes from all users" checkbox.

Have you tried attaching to w3wp.exe?

@FH-Inway Isn't w3wp the full blown IIS rather than IIS Express?

@phuzi Yes, it is.

Hi @Marouane, are you able to see issexpress.exe in your Task Manager? If not, please firstly  run your application that will start an IS Express Worker process.

If you want to attach 'iisexpress.exe' process to start debugging, please firstly make sure that the iisexpress program has been initiated. You can check if process IIS Express exists in Task Manager.

If you want to debug x++ code for D365 finance and operation on local IIS server, please select IIS Express to start your application and it will start an IIS Express Worker process.

After starting a IIS Express process, you can attach the 'iisexpress.exe' process to start debugging.

If there is any misunderstanding, please feel free to let me know.
Hope it can help you.
